# Trace path through login scripts

Tags: linux, authentication, bash

I have a Linux system on which my ~/.bashrc is being called three times when I login. How do I go about figuring out the entire call path for all the scripts being run at login, so I can figure out what I need to edit/stop calling such that my ~/.bashrc only gets called once?

UPDATE: I renamed my ~/.bash_profile, and one of the calls was removed. I renamed my ~/.profile, and my ~/.bashrc stopped being called at all. Removing the `source "${HOME}/.bashrc"` line from my ~/.profile also stopped all calls of ~/.bashrc.

Comment: I'm not going to go through what/why/when gets called. But you can guard the script by defining a variable s.a.: `[[ -z "$BASHRC_LOADED" ]] || source ~/other_rc ; export BASHRC_LOADED=1;`

Comment: I am not sure why such a thing could happen. Having a look at the ~/.bash_profile might be interesting (usually, the ~/.bashrc is called from there, but usually just once). I can not think of any way to trace file calls through login scripts (for single programs/scripts you could use strace, but probably not here) short of patching the kernel (which handles file access calls as far as I know).

Comment: Not exactly what you are looking for, but you can add `set -x` at the top of a script to trace executed commands. Maybe that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The system is babun, and the `/usr/local/etc/babun.bash` script ignores the `${PROFILEREAD}` variable set in the `/etc/profile` script (similar to [Felipe's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3637404/felipe-lema) comment), thus running through the entire login process twice. I added a check for `${PROFILEREAD}` to `/usr/local/etc/babun.bash`, and now it works fine.